# Sudo make Error: make:*** [prepare-compiler-check] Error 1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration, linux-kernel, virtualbox

My problem is like this. When I config kernel by this code "sudo make menuconfig" then i put 'sudo make' like below. Then come this Error. I do not understand why? Can I Fix? How? Thanks!

```
    user@user-VirtualBox:~/linux-4.8$ sudo make
```

Result is

```
    scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
    CHK     include/config/kernel.release
    Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector- 
    strong 
    not supported by compiler
    Makefile:1048: recipe for target 'prepare-compiler-check' 
    failed
    make: * [prepare-compiler-check] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have an old version of compiler. Do `make mrproper`, configure, then try:

`scripts/config --disable CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG`

thereafter `sudo make -jN` can be done (where N - is the number of [jobs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/156569/how-many-make-threads-to-use)).

Useful links: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940812/cannot-use-config-cc-stackprotector-strong-fstack-protector-strong-not-support), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718381/how-to-compile-and-install-custom-mainline-kernel/718662), [3](https://linux.die.net/man/1/make)

Comment: The Error is okay, I want to take 'sudo make' because  i want all of them. But when i put sudo make after every-steps it need to take Y/N/?.  Like below!
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
*
* Restart config...
*
*
* Linux/x86 4.8.0 Kernel Configuration
*
64-bit kernel (64BIT) [Y/n/?] (NEW